# How do I include glad src(glad.c) in visual studio 2017?

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

I am trying to work on opengl using vs c/c++,i have included glfw3 but i am getting error after i include glad.c in the source file of my project .. So how do i include the glad.c for visual studio?
here is the error list:

```
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol glfwWindowHint referenced in function main   
ff  C:\Users\Kira\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\ff\ff\1.obj 1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol gladLoadGLLoader referenced in function main ff
C:\Users\Kira\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\ff\ff\1.obj 1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol glfwInit referenced in function main ff  C:\Users\Kira\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\ff\ff\1.obj 1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol glfwTerminate referenced in function main    ff  C:\Users\Kira\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\ff\ff\1.obj 1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol glfwCreateWindow referenced in function main ff  C:\Users\Kira\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\ff\ff\1.obj 1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol glfwWindowShouldClose referenced in function main    ff  C:\Users\Kira\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\ff\ff\1.obj 1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol glfwSetWindowShouldClose referenced in function "void __cdecl processInput(struct GLFWwindow *)" (?processInput@@YAXPEAUGLFWwindow@@@Z)  ff  C:\Users\Kira\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\ff\ff\1.obj 1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback referenced in function main   ff  C:\Users\Kira\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\ff\ff\1.obj 1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol glfwPollEvents referenced in function main   ff  C:\Users\Kira\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\ff\ff\1.obj 1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol glfwGetKey referenced in function "void __cdecl processInput(struct GLFWwindow *)" (?processInput@@YAXPEAUGLFWwindow@@@Z)    ff  C:\Users\Kira\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\ff\ff\1.obj 1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol glfwMakeContextCurrent referenced in function main   ff  C:\Users\Kira\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\ff\ff\1.obj 1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol glfwSwapBuffers referenced in function main  ff  C:\Users\Kira\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\ff\ff\1.obj 1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol glfwGetProcAddress referenced in function main   ff  C:\Users\Kira\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\ff\ff\1.obj 1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol glad_glClear ff  C:\Users\Kira\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\ff\ff\1.obj 1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol glad_glClearColor    ff  C:\Users\Kira\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\ff\ff\1.obj 1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol glad_glViewport  ff  C:\Users\Kira\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\ff\ff\1.obj 1   
Error   LNK1120 16 unresolved externals ff  C:\Users\Kira\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\ff\x64\Debug\ff.exe 1
```

Comment: This are linker errors. Are linking against the glfw library?

Comment: Is glad.c being built in your project?  You can't just #include the header.  You need to include the C file as well.  On windows you also need the glad_wgl.h and .c files too.